# Alert Popup doesn't show

Tags: ios, swift

I have some code in my project:

```
@IBAction func createAccountAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    if self.emailField.text == "" || self.passwordField.text == ""
    {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message: "Please enter an email and password.", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else
    {
        FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(self.emailField.text!, password: self.passwordField.text!) { (user, error) in

            if error == nil
            {
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Done", message: "Account created!", preferredStyle: .Alert)

                let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
                self.emailField.text = ""
                self.passwordField.text = ""



            }
            else
            {
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .Alert)

                let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

                self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
```

As you can see in the last else statement I have a alertController with the message `Oops` that will show when clicking the **createAccountAction** **button**.

But that happens when the user presses the button and has not filled in anything in the textfields.

**Now what I want is that when a user succesfully fills in the textfields, that a same popup should appear along with other text that I specified.**

When I run the code it does the part

```
 self.emailField.text = ""
 self.passwordField.text = ""
```

but does not present the AlertController.

How can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the line:

```
 self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

which should be after:

```
self.emailField.text = ""
self.passwordField.text = ""
```

So you aren't presenting the alert.

Also. You can change that entire function to this much simpler one:

```
@IBAction func createAccountAction(sender: AnyObject) {

   if self.emailField.text == "" || self.passwordField.text == "" {

        let title = "Oops"
        let message = "Please enter an email and password."

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else {
        FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(self.emailField.text!, password: self.passwordField.text!) { (user, error) in

            var title : String
            var message : String

            if error == nil {
                title = "Done"
                message = "Account created!"
                self.emailField.text = ""
                self.passwordField.text = ""
            } else {
                title = "Oops!"
                message = "error?.localizedDescription"
            }

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixes it... Late night coding will cause you to oversee small simple things like that.. :P

Comment: If you are satisfied with my answer, click the check next to it when you have the chance.

Comment: Will do once the ten minutes go by :)

Comment: I would change `var title = ""` to `let title: String` so it doesn't get assigned twice (and `message` similarly)

Answer (score 0):

You are only presenting the alert controller in the 'else' part of your 'if else' statement.

Additionally refactored example to ensure bugs like that don't happen:

```
    var title: String!
    var message: String!

    if let error = error {
        title = "Oops!"
        message = error.localizedDescription

    } else {
        title = "Done"
        message = "Account created!"

        self.emailField.text = ""
        self.passwordField.text = ""
    }

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```